# warn - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: express, socket.io

Expressjs code:-

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(app.get('port')));
```

gives Error:-

```
info  - socket.io started
warn  - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

Is the error because i'm setting up the app.listen and io.listen on the same port? I want to run a webserver and allow it to communicate with server using socket.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that you're trying to have two separate servers listen on the same port.

You can combine Express and `socket.io` on the same port by using this:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'));
var io     = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: Hello @robertklep can you please tell me where can i add this code since i am newbie to this platform and dont know anything about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nick at some point in your code you start the Express server, which is about the same place you would insert the code I posted (although usually the `app.set()` line will be higher up in your code, *if* you use it at all).

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try once i get that code. which i have not found yet.