# Socket.io Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, webserver, socket.io

I have a small problem. I want to run a webserver and allow it to communicate with server using socket.io but i get:

[image]

**POST UPDATE**

**Chat Class:**

```
/**
 * Chat Class
 */

// module dependencies
var io = require('socket.io'); 
// self instance
var self = this;

/**
 * Constructor 
 *
 * @param {server}
 * @param {userlist}
 */
var Chat = function(server) {
    this.server = server;
};

// Init
Chat.prototype.init = function() {
    // socket instance
    self.sock = io.listen(self.server);
};

module.exports = Chat;
```

**Main:**

```
// socket http server
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    // chat server init
    console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

// chat
var chat = new Chat(server, userlist);
chat.init();
```

**But if i try without chat class encapsulation, it works:**

```
// socket http server
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    // chat server init
    console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require('socket.io'); 

io.listen(self.server);
```

So, what i'm doing bad ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/nodejs-error-listen-eaddrinuse - something is probably already running on tcp/3000.

Comment: @admdrew, thanks for response, but i already was looking that posts, and it's not my case.

Comment: Are you 200% positive? What does `netstat` tell you?

Comment: i'm positive 20000%, because i tried with other ports and the same result.

Comment: Haha ok yeah that is pretty positive. Could it be [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119805/warn-error-raised-error-listen-eaddrinuse)? I'm wondering if your `var server = http.createServer...` and `var chat = new Chat(server, userlist);` lines are trying to create *two* servers on the same port. If you comment out `var chat...` and `chat.init();`, do the errors go away, and can you verify something is already listening on the port you chose?

Comment: I think you are right, i've tried again, but this time without class encapsulation and it worked effectively. But in theory should not happen. Can you suggest me a correct way to implement?

Comment: That I'm not sure about, I don't know enough about best practices for javascript. Sorry, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have object instance problem. Delete `var self = this;`

Replace;

```
self.sock = io.listen(self.server);
```

To:

```
this.sock = io.listen(this.server);
```